# How to locate and disable the Telematics Control Unit?

Tags: mazda, telematics, cx5

I recently purchased a new vehicle. For reference it is a 2023 Mazda CX-5.

This vehicle comes equipped with a [Telematics Control Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telematic_control_unit). More details on how to confirm the TCU are at [this page](https://static.nhtsa.gov/odi/tsbs/2021/MC-10201858-0001.pdf).

There is an option to [disable this in software](https://www.mazdausa.com/static/manuals/mazda-connected-service/chapter4/section12.html), however I am still concerned about the privacy implications of [data being collected and transmitted without my consent](https://foundation.mozilla.org/en/privacynotincluded/articles/its-official-cars-are-the-worst-product-category-we-have-ever-reviewed-for-privacy/).

Are there general instructions on how to physically remove the TCU from a vehicle? The general advice is "just pull the fuse", however the service manual is not clear which fuse correlates to the TCU.

I understand that disabling the TCU will also disable the auto-start feature, location feature, and other features used by the iOS and Android applications. I am OK with that.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](https://www.cx30talk.com/threads/thoughts-on-tcu-disable.3748/) which mentions that the unit is "a small computer under the dash, with a cellular phone signal that allows Mazda's remote computers into your car's CAN bus." So if you can isolate that computer and wrap it in a material which blocks signal, you can be reasonably sure.

There is also a phone tag game you can play with customer service to have them send a disable code which permanently deactivates it. Even if they are lying or creatively telling the truth, probably worth doing.

Oh! I think I found an [official guide](https://mazdamanuals.com.au/wsm-secure/WSM/D9P5-1A-22E_Ver7/esicont/srvc/html/id0922007084f2.html) for install/removal.

Let me know if you have success. I'm going to need a new vehicle soon and I want to do the same thing.